# How to display only the content of webpages(not any of the tags,links) by regular expression in Java program

Tags: java, html, regex

I checked for this specific question and could not find any. I am writing a program in Java which analyses content from web pages, so I need a regular expression which can weed out all the links and tags (`href`, `img`, etc...), so that I could display only the pure content written and visible in the webpages. Thanks a lot.

Hi I wanted to make it more specific:

```
URLConnection connection = wordURL.openConnection("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String line;
String word = "bloom filter";
String regexp2 = word; 
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(regexp2);
String HTML_REGEX = "(<.+?>)+"; // as per your answer(Martijn Courteaux)
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
       String content;
       if ( (content = line.replaceAll(HTML_REGEX, "\n") )!= null)
       {
              Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(line);
              if(matcher2.find())
              {
                   System.out.println(line);
              }
        }
 }
```

But unfortunately it still prints out paragraph (`<p>`) tag and also `<li`> tag with some rubbish inside `</li>`. I would like to restrict it to display only those words where "bloom filter" is present.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I really know it isn't good to use a regex with html.** But if he really wants to this might help:

```
String HTML_REGEX = "<.+?>";
String yourHTML = "<html><body><h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>" + 
                  "<p>Lorem <i>Ipsum</i> dolorem sedet. Set nihil amat. " + 
                  "<sub>I don't know the text</sub></p></body></html>"

String content = yourHTML.replaceAll(HTML_REGEX, "\n");
System.out.println(content);
```

prints:

```
Lorem Impsum

Lorem 
Ipsum
dolorem sedet. Set nihil amat. 
I don't know the text
```

As you can see, it will work, but it is definitely not what you want.

---

You can reduce the number of newlines by using this regex:

```
String HTML_REGEX = "(<.+?>)+";
String yourHTML = "<html><body><h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>" + 
                  "<p>Lorem <i>Ipsum</i> dolorem sedet. Set nihil amat. " + 
                  "<sub>I don't know the text</sub></p></body></html>"

String content = yourHTML.replaceAll(HTML_REGEX, "\n");
System.out.println(content);
```

prints:

```
Lorem Impsum
Lorem 
Ipsum
dolorem sedet. Set nihil amat. 
I don't know the text
```

---

I tried your code, and it didn't work indeed. After some editing this worked:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter").openConnection();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String line;
String word = "bloom filter".toLowerCase();
String HTML_REGEX = "(<.+?>)+"; // as per your answer(Martijn Courteaux)
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String content;
    if ((content = line.replaceAll(HTML_REGEX, "\n")) != null) {
        if (content.toLowerCase().contains(word)) /* Changed: regex match -> contains() */
        {
            System.out.println(content); /* CHANGED: line -> content */
        }
    }
}
```

What you did wrong was:

1. You didn't print `content`, but `line` which of course contains the tags...
2. You tried to find the `word` "`bloom filter`" using a regex, which is case sensitive. So, just lowercase the strings and use [`String.contains(CharSequence target)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), which tells you if the target string is a part of the whole string.

Comment: Hi, your answer certainly helped but could help me modify the code(above) to restrict it as per my new edited question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, but remember that you should use a parser like JSoup.

Answer (score 5):

HTML isn't regular so you can't do what you want with a regex but you can use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

> jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.

In particular you might like the following which is outlined in [one of the examples](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-body-fragment)...

```
String html = "<div><p>Lorem ipsum.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
Element body = doc.body();
```

Answer (score 2):

[Don't use RegEx for HTML parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an HTML parser, for example [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) or [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).